# Pandas arithmetic over block of select data on columns with condition from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame from Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'c1':1, 'c2':100}, {'c1':1,'c2':110}, {'c1':1,'c2':120},{'c1':2, 'c2':130}, {'c1':2,'c2':140}, {'c1':2,'c2':150},
       {'c1':3, 'c2':160}, {'c1':3,'c2':170}, {'c1':3,'c2':180} , {'c1':2, 'c2':190}, {'c1':2,'c2':200}, {'c1':2,'c2':210},
       {'c1':4, 'c2':220}, {'c1':4,'c2':230}, {'c1':4,'c2':240}, {'c1':1, 'c2':250}, {'c1':1,'c2':260}, {'c1':1,'c2':270}
      ]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
print (df)
```

Output

```
    c1   c2
0    1  100
1    1  110
2    1  120
3    2  130
4    2  140
5    2  150
6    3  160
7    3  170
8    3  180
9    2  190
10   2  200
11   2  210
12   4  220
13   4  230
14   4  240
15   1  250
16   1  260
17   1  270
```

Now I would like to do a few things on this:

1. I'd like to find where the value in **c1** is changing which can be done by `diff()`
2. Then I'd like to average the n values of **c2** starting from where **c1** changed. For example if n = 2 , I would want to get

> mean(100, 110) = 105
>
> mean(130, 140) = 135
>
> mean(160,170) = 165
>
> mean(190,200) = 195
>
> mean(220,230) = 225
>
> mean(250,260) = 255

Note that `groupby()` won't work for this as the value of c1 can go up and back down to an earlier value and I would like to track the change in c1, segment that section regardless of the value of c1 and do the arithmetic on c2 for the next n values of that block of c1 values

any suggestion how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`groupby agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate) + [`head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html#pandas-dataframe-head) + [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html#pandas-dataframe-mean) with groups created via [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html#pandas-series-cumsum) based on where `c1` change:

```
n = 2
new_df = (
    df.groupby(df['c1'].ne(df['c1'].shift()).cumsum(), as_index=False)
        .agg(lambda g: g.head(n).mean())
)
```

`new_df`:

```
   c1   c2
0   1  105
1   2  135
2   3  165
3   2  195
4   4  225
5   1  255
```

---

Explainations:

See this DataFrame Below:

```
explanation_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'c1': df['c1'],
    'c1.shift': df['c1'].shift(),
    'c1.ne.shift': df['c1'].ne(df['c1'].shift()),
    'c1.ne.shift.cumsum (groups)':
        df['c1'].ne(df['c1'].shift()).cumsum()
})
```

```
c1  c1.shift  c1.ne.shift  c1.ne.shift.cumsum (groups)
 1       NaN         True                            1
 1       1.0        False                            1
 1       1.0        False                            1
 2       1.0         True                            2
 2       2.0        False                            2
 2       2.0        False                            2
 3       2.0         True                            3
 3       3.0        False                            3
 3       3.0        False                            3
 2       3.0         True                            4
 2       2.0        False                            4
 2       2.0        False                            4
 4       2.0         True                            5
 4       4.0        False                            5
 4       4.0        False                            5
 1       4.0         True                            6
 1       1.0        False                            6
 1       1.0        False                            6
```

By `shift`ing `c1` we can compare each `c1` to the previous row. In this case the comparision is `ne` (not equal). Anywhere c1 does not equal the previous row's value a `True` appears. Because `True` values when treated as numbers are `1` and `False` values are `0`, we can take the cumulative sum. Each `True` value is `1` every `False` value has no affect on the cumulative sum as `0` is the additive identity.

These values then become the "groups" to `groupby` with. Each group then is aggregated with a `lambda` function to take the first `n` values with `head`, and then the `mean` is taken from the filtered group frame.

Comment: Thanks, the issue with my dataframe is that C1 could go up and back down to the same value, however I would like to do the mean operation on each segment where it changes.  I tried groupby() and didn't get the result I needed as it groups multiple sections of C1 if they are identical. The data is a timeseries with sensor data collection and I would like to do the averaging operation starting from each time the data changes regardless of if it repeated later or not

Comment: @user4298456 check the edit and see if that works as expected.

Comment: That is pretty awesome, thanks. I need to get better at Pandas!

Comment: Thanks again, if you have some time, would you kindly walk me through some of the operations in the line? I understand some but not all of it, thanks!

Comment: See the edit with explanations. I think the harder part is the c1.shift.ne.cumsum bit so I put it in a Frame so the steps can be seen side-by-side.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot for the explanation. I understand it now